# SELECT statement not selecting the correct fields in Dreamweaver

Tags: mysql, dreamweaver

**I have the following SELECT:**

```
  SELECT cit.city,
           providd.base_city
    FROM
      (SELECT prov.id AS prov_id,
              prov.company_name,
              prov.description AS prov_description,
              prov.photo,
              prov.base_city,
              prov.facebook,
              prov.twitter,
              cat.id AS cat_id,
              pcc.city_id
       FROM `providers` AS prov
       LEFT  JOIN `provider_city_category` AS pcc ON prov.id = pcc.provider_id
       LEFT  JOIN `categories` AS cat ON pcc.category_id = cat.id
       WHERE cat.id =7
         AND pcc.city_id =1) AS providd,
         cities cit
    WHERE providd.base_city = cit.id LIMIT 1
```

I have created a SELECT statement in the Advanced area in Dreamweaver and when I press the Testing button it works perfectly but if I click ok I see other fields selected in the Bindings Panel. Why isn't this working in the Bindings panel? It is not selecting the outer statement just the one between parentheses.

**When I test I see selected:**

the cit.city and providd.base_city

**But if I save and look in the Bindings Panel I have these fields:**

prov_id

company_name

prov_description

photo

base_city

facebook

twitter

cat_id

city_id

I don't think there is something wrong with Dreamweaver I think I'm doing something wrong with this statement. I'm working locally and pasted this in phpmyadmin and it works there too just like in the testing environment of Dreamweaver but not in the Bindings Panel. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select is absolutely correct.

I guess that dreamweaver has a bug (or feature) where it executes the most inner subselect or something.

But you can rewrite the query easily to not use a subselect:

```
SELECT cit.city,
       prov.base_city
FROM providers prov
  JOIN cities cit
    ON prov.base_city = cit.id
  LEFT JOIN provider_city_category pcc ON prov.id = pcc.provider_id
  LEFT JOIN categories cat ON pcc.category_id = cat.id
WHERE cat.id =7
  AND pcc.city_id =1
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought it was my fault but was confused by the fact that it was working when I was testing it in the database manager. Dreamweaver seems to have a problem with those parentheses.